# Batch Script on CMD to get COM port on a variable

Tags: batch-file, cmd, port

I want to store the information of my available COM ports and store them on a variable.

The command must run in a script. Searching only I found this command which works perfectly:

```
wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:table| find "COM"
```

It returns:

```
USB-SERIAL CH340 (COM6)
```

Which is the device I want it to recognize. On this Information I need to extract `COM6` or `6`.

Comment: Do you mean "batch" script, perhaps?

Comment: Ops, sorry for the typo. Can you help me out Benjamin? Seems pretty easy but i'm having a hard time here.

Comment: Parse the output with a `for /f` on cmd line: `for /f "tokens=2delims=()" %A in ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:table^| find "COM"') do set "COM=%A"` In a batch-file double the `%%A`.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know anything about batch scripting, only Bash ;)

Comment: instead of `get caption` try `get *` to see what other fields might be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update**: This is the more **short** version for to get only the <kbd>**N**</kbd> part from <kbd>**COM3**</kbd>

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %%i in ('mode ^| findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]"') do set "_com=%%i" & echo/!_com!
```

> - **:: or ::**

```bat
@echo off && setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %%i in ('mode^|findstr /C:"COM"')do set "_com=%%i"&echo/!_com!
```

:: **batch result** <kbd>**3**</kbd> ::

> **Obs.:** For command line use: <kbd>**for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %%i in ('mode^|findstr "COM"')do set "_com=%i"& call echo/%_com%**</kbd>

---

> Pure batch solution...

for bat file, may suggest use **`chgport`** to do this or **`Reg Query`**

By **`chgport`**:

by using this variable: **`!_com_[%%L]!`** to get <kbd>COM</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

by using this variable: **`%%L`** to get <kbd>n</kbd>

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion & set "_cnt=0"
cd /d "%systemroot%" 
for /f "tokens=* delims= " %%C in ('where /r . chgport.exe') do set "_chgport=%%~fC"
for /f "delims== tokens=1,2" %%i in ('!_chgport! ^| findstr /v "#"') do set /a "_cnt+=1" && set "_com_[!_cnt!]=%%i ^= %%j"
popd & echo/COM[n]:  DEVICE[id]: & for /l %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!) do echo/!_com_[%%L]!

:: for get number only :: By using %%C**
for /l %%L in (1 1 !_cnt!) do for /f %%C in ('echo/!_com_[%%L]:COM^=!') do set "_com_N=%%C" & echo/ !_com_N! = COM%%C
```

> :: Commandline result ::

```bat
COM[n]:  DEVICE[id]:
COM3  =  \Device\huawei_cdcacm_AcmSerial1
COM4  =  \Device\huawei_cdcacm_AcmSerial0
 3 = COM3
 4 = COM4
```

[image]

By **`Reg Query`** :
by using this variable: **`!_com#!`** to get <kbd>COM</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd>

by using this variable: **`!_com#:COM=!`** to get <kbd>n</kbd>

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
set _key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\HARDWARE\DEVICEMAP\SERIALCOMM"
for /f "tokens=1,3 delims= " %%i in ('reg query !_key! ^| find /v "HKEY"') do (
   set "_device=%%i" & set "_com#=%%j" & echo/!_com#! !_device! )

:: for get number only :: By using !_com_N:~3! to get [n]
for /f "tokens=3 delims= " %%c in ('reg query !_key! ^| find /v "HKEY"') do set "_com_N=%%c"&& echo/!_com_N:~3! = !_com_N!
```

> :: Commandline result ::

```bat
COM4 \Device\huawei_cdcacm_AcmSerial0
COM3 \Device\huawei_cdcacm_AcmSerial1
4 = COM4
3 = COM3
```

[image]

Sorry, English isn’t my first language..

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it in a cmd .bat script file. This will result in the last com port being set. I do not see any indication as to how multiple com ports are to be handled.

```
@ECHO OFF
FOR /F "delims=^T tokens=1,2" %%a IN ('powershell -NoLogo -NoProfile -Command ^
    "Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnPEntity |" ^
        "Where-Object { $_.Name -match '.*\(COM(\d)\)'} | Out-Null;" ^
        "$Matches[0] + '^t' + $Matches[1]"') DO (
    SET "CPNAME=%%a"
    SET "CPNUM=%%b"
)

ECHO CPNAME is %CPNAME%
ECHO CPNUM is %CPNUM%
```

It is, of course, easier without the cmd.exe overhead if using PowerShell directly. You could save the following code in `comport.ps1`.

```
Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_PnPEntity |
    Where-Object { $_.Name -match '.*\(COM(\d)\)' } | Out-Null
$cpname = $Matches[0]
$cpnum = $Matches[1]

$cpname
$cpnum
```

Answer (score -1):

You will need a `for /F` loop to parse the output of this command. Even though this will not work, because my computer output `Intel(R)*(COM3)`, we talk about your computer and a specific output. I suggest you to use:

```bat
for /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%A IN ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:table ^| findstr /c:"COM"') do echo %%A
```

This, will `echo` the information. To store it in a variable, use `set "com_info=%%A"`.

You said also, that you would like to extract `6` from `COM6`. This is also possible; use:

```bat
for /F "tokens=2 delims=()" %%A IN ('wmic path win32_pnpentity get caption /format:table ^| findstr /c:"COM"') do set "com_info=%%A"&call set "com_num=%com_info:~-1%"
```

Replace `echo` with `set` or the opposite where you want to `echo` and the opposite.

In cmd, replace `%%A` with `%A` where presented.