# Use findstr regular expressions to search for patterns in piped results

Tags: batch-file, cmd, pipe, findstr

I want to search for the pattern `(COM\d+)` in the output of `mode` command. I have tried the:

```
mode | findstr /R (COM\d+)
```

But it doesn't return anything. I would appreciate if you could help me know what is the correct way to do this.

**P.S.1** Thanks to the comments I now have the `mode | findstr /RC:"COM[0-9*]"` which yields the line with the given match. Now I need to find a way to print out just the match. maybe using  the `for /f ... in` to loop the string?

**P.S.2** I'm being told that `mode | findstr /RC:"COM[123456789][0123456789]*"` is a safer option.

Comment: `findstr /?` at a command prompt documents the available options, including a quick reference for regexes.

Comment: @KenWhite I did read some documentations and examples. The issue is that I couldn't find any example for searching piped results with regular expression.

Comment: This type of regex is not supported in batch. What you have to try is `mode | findstr /RC:"COM[0-9*]"` which should work

Comment: @double-beep aha. So it is not "regular" regular expression? what you gave is nice, it gives me the entire line like `grep` but I need the exact match, ignoring the rest of the line.

Comment: This is the type of regex `findstr` supports and it isn't possible to echo exact match

Comment: @double-beep no other cmd/batch command doing that then?

Comment: Findstr does not use `\d`, which is why I referred you to its regex documentation. Read my comment again. :-)

Comment: @KenWhite that I just realized. :)  that is solved by using `[0-9*]` instead. the problem is to show just the match not the entire line.

Comment: From [here](https://superuser.com/questions/524822/awk-equivalent-functionality-on-windows) it seams that I can use `for /f ... in` to find the exact match

Comment: @double-beep, you've got a type, the asterisk must be outside of the brackets, so it's `[0-9]*` to match zero or more decimal digits, or `[0-9][0-9]*` to match one or more such; note that this character class `[0-9]` might actually also match characters like `²`, `³`, depending on the current code page; to prevent that you'd need `[0123456789]` instead...

Comment: From the Command Prompt, `For /F Delims^=: %A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*:"')Do @For %B In (%A)Do @Set "var=%B"`, or from a batch, `@For /F Delims^=: %%A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*:"')Do @For %%B In (%%A)Do @Set "var=%%B"` Any match would be saved as a variable, `%var%`.

Comment: @Compo wow, that's one heck of a command. would please be so kind to elaborate it?

Comment: No, I wouldn't!

Comment: @Compo did you tested yourself though? it did not work for me!

Comment: The `findstr` command always returns full lines that contain a match (or that do not contain any if `/V` is given), it cannot return partial lines; you're right, `for /F` can be used to split the returned lines; to suggest something useful you should provide some sample input lines...

Comment: @Foad, no I didn't need to test and very rarely do, _as I do not have a Windows PC_. If you're unable to copy and paste or read my comments, you're beyond my help! My commands work both at the Command Prompt and within a batch file, exactly as posted, did you bother to check the variable those short commands created? or were you just expecting to see the output directly without asking to see it?

Comment: @Compo [Here a gif](https://media.giphy.com/media/w9mAi3vYRAvFUUu3aK/giphy.gif) showing the result is just empty

Comment: You haven't asked to see the variable value! Do you not know the `Set` and/or `Echo` commands?

Comment: @compo Sorry, thanks for clarification. How can I echo it then?

Comment: At the Command Prompt enter `echo /?` and read the extensive usage information.

Comment: @Compo thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here's two simple examples according to my comments:

From the Command Prompt, to satisfy your [cmd](/questions/tagged/cmd) tag:

```dos
(For /F Delims^=: %A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*:"')Do @For %B In (%A)Do @Set "var=%B")&Call Echo(%var%
```

From a batch file, to satisfy your [batch-file](/questions/tagged/batch-file) tag:

```bat
@(For /F Delims^=: %%A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*:"')Do @For %%B In (%%A)Do @Set "var=%%B")&Call Echo(%%var%%&Pause
```

---

To supplement my comment about WMI, you could alternatively try:

From the Command Prompt:

```dos
For /F Skip^=1Delims^= %A In ('WMIC Path Win32_SerialPort Get DeviceID 2^>Nul')Do @For %B In (%A)Do @Echo(%B
```

From a batch file:

```bat
@For /F Skip^=1Delims^= %%A In ('WMIC Path Win32_SerialPort Get DeviceID 2^>Nul')Do @For %%B In (%%A)Do @Echo(%%B&Pause
```

Comment: Thanks. The first command exports the last match, but not the rest. I thin we should also use tokens (`token=4`?) to say that we need just the `COM*` part. Tryingto figure it out

Comment: the command `For /F "tokens=4 Delims= " %A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*:"')Do @For %B In (%A)Do @echo %B` come very close. I just need to remove the double dot at the end now.

Comment: Well if you want to specifically limit the script to a particular language, you can do whatever you like. You need to be aware that the output of commands do not necessarily carry the same number of words in all languages. Also my script already removes the trailing colon, **`:`**, can you not use the same method? Your question was about searching for a pattern, not how to parse every result and perform your entire task for you.

Comment: sorry for the not clear question. I basically need the same behavior as `(COM\d+)` in a conventional regex search. I'm also not sure what you mean by different languages. I just need to run a cmd command from another program  to get the exact available COM* ports.

Comment: All you need to do is to implement a counter, saving each to a separate variable incremented with that counter, or try to be clever and concatenate each result to a single variable. The alternative, depending upon what you're specifically wanting to do is to use WMI.

Comment: aha, figured it out. you can have multiple `delims` :) --> `For /F "tokens=4 Delims=: " %A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*"')Do @For %B In (%A)Do @echo %B` just a space after `:`

Comment: a shorter version `For /F "tokens=4 Delims=: " %A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*"')Do @Echo %A`

Comment: the first command from your second section (third piece of code) does exactly what the code in above command does.

Comment: I have edited my answer to include a WMI example! Of course the 'even shorter' version you've shown is still limited by the systems language, mine was extended specifically to prevent that limitation, but if its only for use on known systems of that language that's fine.

Comment: Would you be kind to explain what you mean by system language? I want to run it on Windows. isn't the case that all common versions of Windows have same syntax?

Comment: Do you think that a German, French, Spanish etc. system would see the English words `Status for device COM1:` from their Mode command?

Comment: Well, That I had not thought about at all!!! is it different though? how people handle this then?

Comment: FYI to have everything in one line --> `For /F "tokens=4 Delims=: " %A In ('Mode^|FindStr "COM[0-9]*"')Do @(@Echo|@Set /p="%A ")`

Comment: Did you try my `WMIC` alternatives?

Comment: I did check it and it works fine. Is `WMIC` some sort of powershell interface? because the following commands are PS AFIK.

Comment: one issue about the `WMIC Path Win32_SerialPort Get DeviceID` is that it gives you all the ports open and available. while mode only shows the available serial ports and that's what I  need.

Comment: Nothing whtsover to do with PowerShell. It is simply a command line interface for Windows Management and Instumentation. It isn't the easiest of commands to work with, but its Query Language can be pretty useful. So in the case of your latest comment you could filter through it using, for instance, something like `WMIC Path Win32_SerialPort Where "MaxBaudRate='115200' And ProviderType Like 'RS232%'" Get DeviceID`. Take a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/cimwin32prov/win32-serialport) for the options you can filter with.

Comment: I mixed it up with `Get-WMIObject` from [here](https://superuser.com/a/835853/588662). In the case you think what crazy mind should do these things, I'm trying to develop a replica of MATLAB serial port comunication for SciLab/ScicosLab here. Although Scilab has `dos` and `powershell` and `regexp` ... commands, ScicosLab doesn't. The only thing  I have is `unix_g` which runs cmd commands.

Comment: Take a look at the how `PowerShell` would perform the task then, and see if you can replicate it with `WMIC`. Be warned though, it can be frustrating at times, will not be easy and will probably make you want to give up before you achieve what you wanted.

Comment: It is frustrating indeed. See [this](https://gist.github.com/Foadsf/44fe9b5e2bcb02b22392adf6d8f7a871). To achieve what I need I'm interfacing to cmd/batch, PowerShell, Tcl, C/C++... at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

So, why not just use only one **`for`** loop command and addind  **`\`** for literal find COM+RegEx in **`FindStr`** by this:  **`"\C\O\M[0-9*]."`**

> **Obs.:** For some reason, the command line do not work for echoing in first run, the **COM** number for **`echo/%_com%`** command, only in second run work, but adding **`Call`** to **`echo/%_com%`** command, the result showing in first running...

- **In command line:**

```bat
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %i in ('mode ^| findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]."') do set "_com=%i"&& call echo/%_com%
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %i in ('mode ^| findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]."') do set "_com=COM%i"&& call echo/%_com%
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %i in ('mode ^| findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]."') do set "_com=COM%i:"&& call echo/%_com%
```

> - result 1st line command:          **3**
> - result 2nd line command: **COM3**
> - result 3rd line command: **COM3:**

- **Or** in **batch file:**

```bat
@echo off & setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %%i in ('mode ^| findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]."') do set "_com=%%i"&& echo/!_com!
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %%i in ('mode ^| findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]."') do set "_com=COM%%i"&& echo/!_com!
for /f "tokens=2delims=COM:" %%i in ('mode ^| findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]."') do set "_com=COM%%i:"&& echo/!_com!
```

> - result 1st <kbd>**for**</kbd> command:          **3**
> - result 2nd <kbd>**for**</kbd> command: **COM3**
> - result 3rd <kbd>**for**</kbd> command: **COM3:**

See your self by command line:

```bat
mode | findstr /RC:"\C\O\M[0-9*]."
```

> - result: **Status para dispositivo COM3:**

*So sorry my limited **English***

Comment: Thanks lot. I will look into this.

Comment: you linked to the same post :)

Comment: This [answer] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717590/batch-script-on-cmd-to-get-com-port-on-a-variable/54726086#54726086) the link is this one ..

Comment: The nice part of your question is that this one make me **Update** my [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54717590/batch-script-on-cmd-to-get-com-port-on-a-variable/54726086#54726086)in this platform so, I need say thank to you too.. **Thx**!

Comment: @Foad there is not same question, the OP needs is the take the com number too, but not use the RegEx in FindSTR command! Soh, is different one!

Comment: @Foad I tried to find an error but I could not find it, did you find any?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you just want "COM1" or "COM3" as the output.  If so, this'll do it:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=: " %A in ('mode ^| findstr /i /r "COM[0-9]*:"') do @echo %A
```

It'll produce the following output:

```
COM1
```